# NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: returning nil

Tags: ios, json, parsing, url, nsdata

```
NSString *jsonPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"CRN_JSON"
                                                     ofType:@"json"];


dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                    [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://properfrattire.com/Classifi/CRN_JSON.json"]];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:)
                           withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];

});
```

My data variable is nil after running this code. If you follow the link you'll see that it is a JSON file. I've run the function with this exact same file locally but it is not able to obtain the data at the given URL without error.

Comment: It's not that there's an error. It's just you expecting an asynchronous call to behave as if it was synchronous.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: You expect that the sequence of commands in the block passed to dispatch_async is executed in order, and is finished after the function returns. However, since it's **async,** this won't happen - the function returns before the block finishes running. What isn't obvious in this? Haven't you read the documentation for `dispatch_async()`?

Comment: I'm just following this http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5 tutorial, I'm new to this and don't fully understand what I need to change to make it work. Can you say specifically what I need to change?

Comment: The problem is where you're checking the contents of your data. If it's right after the `dispatch_async()` call, it will be nil as the network code hasn't had time to complete. The network code runs concurrently (in parallel) with the main code. That's what async means. So where are you checking data?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you're nesting calls to `URLWithString:`

```
[NSURL URLWithString:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://properfrattire.com/Classifi/CRN_JSON.json"]]];
```

Once will do:

```
[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://properfrattire.com/Classifi/CRN_JSON.json"];
```

Also, you should use `dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:` so you can see any error.

Comment: Sorry Yeah I just typed it into here wrong thats what I actually have but it still doesnt work.

Comment: @BryceLanglotz IT's important to PASTE the REAL code when asking a question. Typing in fake code makes is much harder to help find the problem.